# drawing at least 90% of colors from urn with large populations

Tags: probability-distributions

My problem is: suppose I have an urn containing balls of $n = 10000000$ (i.e., $10^7$) different colors, with $1000$ balls of each color (so the total number of balls is $1000n = 10^{10}$). Suppose I draw $100000000$ (i.e. $10^8 = 10n$) balls. My question is:

how do I calculate the probability that I have drawn at least 90% (in this case $1000000$ or $10^6$) of the different colors?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should merge this with [your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446619/drawing-at-least-one-colored-ball-of-each-from-urn-in-a-case-of-large-population) about the urn with $10^{10}$ balls of $10^7$ colors.

Comment: So you mean you have $1000\cdot 10000000$ balls, colored equally amongst $10000000$ different colors? Because the first sentence strongly implies that there are only $10^7$ balls.

Comment: @Thomas OP seems to have meant "10000000 different **colors of** balls".

Comment: Hi Thomas, yes the total is 1000x10000000 (10 to the 10th)

Comment: Hi MJD, with my very weak knowledge of Statistics, I thought they are different since one question you have a fixed number of drawn balls and I need to calculate the probability that I might have catched 90% of all the colors; instead the other question is asking what the number of draws should be to ensure to get 90% of all the colors.

Comment: Please do not post a question [more than once](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/446631).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a simple question to answer.  The naive approach would be to say we can pick the colors not to see in ${10^7 \choose 10^6}$ ways, then each pull has a $0.9$ chance of avoiding them, so we get a probability of ${10^7 \choose 10^6}0.9^{10^8}$.  Unfortunately, this double counts the events were we miss $10^6+1$ of the colors and overcounts even worse when we miss more colors.  But it is an upper bound, and so small we don't need to worry about the overcount.  [Alpha gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2810%5E7%20choose%2010%5E6%29%2a0.9%5E%2810%5E8%29) $9.61097262395 \times 10^{-3163936}$ so you have a great chance of seeing at least $90\%$.  In your other question you see there is a poor (but *much* better chance than missing more than $10\%$) chance of seeing them all.

Comment: Does the value from alpha calculator represent the probability of not getting 90% of the colors?

Comment: Yes, that is a calculation of the chance of seeing less than $90\%$, but is too high.